# Display UIImageView like books on tableself objective c

Tags: objective-c

How to display UIImageView like displayed in attached link image.

[Book Shelf](http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/307328_2857930102889_507159741_n.jpg)

Comment: Check if link you provided is working. Don't put spam links..

Comment: This image is linked to your profile, however outsiders don't have access to the image. Simplest thing is -> RIght click on image, choose 'view Image' and it will open the url and image, copy the URL here and modify your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestand you right, you can rotate your UIImageView with `CATransform3DMakeRotation` . And dont' forget move your image with `CATransform3DMakeTranslation`, otherwise you get effets like in [Rotate 3D got issue in X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231572/rotate-3d-got-issue-in-x-axis/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel), perfect solution to solve your problem.